# How to not retry a Scrapy request?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-request

Sometimes I don't want to retry on an error in a Scrapy request since I am only checking if the page exists. How to not retry a request?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it has `dont_retry` argument.

```
Request('myurl', callback=self.method_to_parse, meta={'dont_retry':True})
```